# No hint path defined for [voyager ]

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I'm trying to create a custom admin page and Menu in Laravel Voyager.

This is the error that I'm getting.

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
No hint path defined for [voyager ]. (View: /Users/jake/code/DS/resources/views/vendor/voyager/orders/order.blade.php)
```

This is my web.php file

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();
});

Route::get('/admin/orders', function () {
    return view('vendor/voyager/orders/order');
});
```

This is my resources/views/vendor/voyager/orders/order.php

```
@extends ('voyager::master')

@section('content')
    <h1>Hello There</h1>
@stop
```

When I add `TCG\Voyager\VoyagerServiceProvider::class,` to app.php it displays the page but other things like `$dataTypeContent` don't work. I'm using Laravel 5.6 whereby I thought Voyager is auto-discovered. Am I doing something wrong?

Any Help would be great.

Thanks, Jake.

Comment: For one thing , I think you need to change your "extends" to be "@extends('voyager.master')"  - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade.

Comment: @RoboBear In doing so it causes the issue I was having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error is coming from this route:

```
Route::get('/admin/orders', function () {
    return view('vendor/voyager/orders/order');
});
```

Try changing the return to:

```
return view('voyager::orders.order');
```

Another thing, `resources/views/vendor/voyager/orders/order.php` is missing the `blade` portion, so `resources/views/vendor/voyager/orders/order.blade.php`